# Hide next button until an answer is selected [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

I want to set a condition to check if the user has selected an answer. If the user has selected an answer then display the next button. Been stuck trying to figure this out for a while.

**JSFiddle:**
[source code](https://jsfiddle.net/0xx7j7g0/4/)

I'd imagine it would be something as simple as adding but not sure.

```
  if (check if user has selected an answer) {
    document.getElementById('btnNxt').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btnNxt').style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest disabling the button rather than hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xx7j7g0/64/). You just need to add `disabled` attribute when question is loaded and removed this attribute when answer is selected.

Something like

```
  function myAnswer() {
   document.getElementById('btnNxt').removeAttribute("disabled");
```

and

```
 btnNxt.onclick = function() {
 buildQuiz(page + 1)
 document.getElementById('btnNxt').setAttribute("disabled", true); 
  };
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, works if you go through the quiz but if you go back a set you have to reselect an answer again when there is already 1 selected

Comment: Ah. didn't notice that. check this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0xx7j7g0/65/

Comment: Hey mate, almost there the only issue with it now is that if you answer to question 3 then go back to question 1 you cannot get passed question 2 even tho you have selected an answer.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: solved it by adding on btnPre.onclick = function() Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener that makes the button visible when an answer is selected.
"answerOptions".addEventListener('click', makeNextButtonVisible)
[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the next button on default using CSS:

```
#btnNxt{
    display: none
}
```

Then modify the `hideShow` function:

```
function hideshow() {
  if (0 >= page) {
    document.getElementById('btnPre').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('btnPre').style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (myObj.length <= page) {
    document.getElementById('btnNxt').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnPre').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    //commented the part below
    //document.getElementById('btnNxt').style.display = 'block';
  }
```

Hide the button again on click:

```
btnNxt.onclick = function() {
  buildQuiz(page + 1)
    document.getElementById('btnNxt').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Then show it `myAnswer` function:

```
function myAnswer() {
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btnNxt");
    btn_next.style.display = 'block';
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/0xx7j7g0/62/)
But like what has suggested here, I would disable rather than hiding it.

Comment: If you answer to question 3 then go back to question 1 you cannot click next unless you reselect the question any solution?